# How should I run a regression on cointegrated variables?

Tags: regression, stationarity, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

The variables are non-stationary for levels but become stationary for first differences, in other words they are $I(1)$. Also they have been already  further checked for cointegration using Johansen and Engle-Granger two-step procedures, in both cases they have come out to be cointegrated.

Comment: Instead of Eigenvalue, do you perhaps mean Engle-Granger? Or do you mean Johansen's trace and eigenvalue tests (two versions of Johansen's test)? Anyway, consider using the vector error correction model (VECM), it is the standard approach for cointegrated variables. You may find information about the VECM online and also in quite a few posts [here at Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vecm).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I meant Engle-Granger two step procedure and the Johansen ( Trace and Eigen-value tests). All have confirmed cointegration of the non stationary at level but stationary on first difference series. The problem is I want to test the parameters in the regression by placing restrictions on the same . Would Dynamic OLS be the solution to this?

Comment: Perhaps, I have no experience with dynamic OLS, but it seems to be a valid approach. You can also test restrictions in VECM, that should be no problem. See e.g. Pfaff ["Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R"](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9780387759661).

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I read through literature on Dynamic OLS, it suggests that DOLS can be used on  the variables which  are non stationary at level ( but I(1) and cointegrated). Hope it just works out fine.